# Limit the size of Google Desktop's index?

Tags: file-management, google-desktop-search

I've been using [Google Desktop](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdesktop.google.com%2F&rct=j&q=google%20desktop&ei=3TYKTZClCcKblgfA49SsAQ&usg=AFQjCNHynR4q4og5GoEenhJTyMzva51SAA&sig2=He9zBd0yZTz42JEEzQyYmA&cad=rja) for almost 2 years now.  I needed a little more space on my hard drive, so I poked about with [WinDirStat](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwindirstat.info%2F&rct=j&q=win%20dir%20stat&ei=0TYKTZSGKYL6lweo58GdDA&usg=AFQjCNFgnT9h2e1rSSEwfoJFHUL7lzBHuA&sig2=-_g5F-LB4CHM_Vr8tsIFSQ&cad=rja) and found my Google Desktop index file was taking up 6.1 GB (on a 60 GB HD)!  I've deleted it, so it has to start over, but how can I keep the index from getting so bloated in the future?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but why are you still using it? The built in search on Windows is equally as good, and doesn't require such a large index. (I might be wrong, haven't used GDesktop for at least 6 years!)

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw Still stuck on XP at work.  Hopefully upgrading to Win7 soon.

Comment: Ah, nightmare! Isn't that like ten years old now?

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw, yes.  Welcome to corporate America.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using NTFS compression on the folder, but I'm not sure how much that will help. I remember doing it in the old days before Windows 7 came along, but I don't recall what compression level I got.